# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v7/users/@me

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, callback, discord

I'm making a login system with Discord using the [discord-oauth package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-oauth2)  ... But it gives this error of unauthorized
**(UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordHTTPError: 401 Unauthorized on GET /api/v7/users/@me)**

**Code:**

```js
const router = require('express').Router()
const crypto = require('crypto')
const DiscordOauth2 = require('discord-oauth2') 
const request = require('snekfetch')

const rateLimit = require('../middleware/limiterBotControler.js')
const baseUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/v7/'

const oauth = new DiscordOauth2({
    clientId: '782761260620972034',
    clientSecret: '',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/login/discord/callback'
})

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {

    let url = oauth.generateAuthUrl({
        scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds'],
        state: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex')
    })

    return res.redirect(url)
})

router.get('/login/discord/callback', (req, res) => {
    let code = req.query.code

    oauth.tokenRequest({
        code: code,
        grantType: 'authorization_code',
        scope: ['identify', 'email', 'guilds']
    }).then((refresh_token) => {
        oauth.getUser(refresh_token).then(console.log)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a similar issue myself, although I'm pretty sure it doesn't have the same causes as you. Here's the mistakes I've noticed.

mistake 1) tokenRequest doesn't return a refresh_token, it returns an object that contains
`{ access_token, refresh_token, ...etc }`

mistake 2) getUser takes an access_token, you however are attempting to do this with a refresh_token

Hope this helps ^-^